# wordpress Account Management generate password missing on my laptop

Tags: users, admin, password

The button to generate a new password is completely missing in my user accounts on my laptop. Wondering if this could be a security thing? I run a few wordpress accounts and it isn't showing in any of them - but ONLY on my laptop. It isn't showing either for an existing user or a new one.

[image: GENERATE PASSWORD MISSING]

Comment: That button is still present on my own install, but this isn't something we could debug from a screenshot. If it's only on your laptop that implies some sort of ad blocker/browser/malware incompatibility. I'd suggest making sure your browser etc are up to date, or using another browser ( based on the dropdown menu for roles I'm guessing this is MS Edge or Internet Explorer )

Comment: It could be any number of things. try standard trouble-shooting techniques of disabling plugins one by one until the problem goes away and try using one of the default WP themes (2017, 2018, etc).